# Unable to download file on Google Chrome. Same is working on mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a .war file and I want the user to download it on click of a button.
But when I'm trying this on chrome it is opening that file instead of prompting user to save the file.
[image: Image donwnloaded after click of button]
Same is working fine on mozilla.

Comment: Please show us the code that produced this. And where is the file hosted? Without this info we can only guess at what the problem might be,

Answer (score 0):

You need `download` attribute on your anchor tag.

```
<a href="/path/to/your/file.war" download>Download File</a>
```

**Note: On Chrome, you cannot download cross-origin files , they have to be hosted on the same domain.**